# How can I determine which button was clicked within a recycleview/cardview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Referring to Jacob Tabok's post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26196831/3600178), I added an OnItemTouchListener to my Fragment's onCreateView here:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recyclerview, container, false);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_recylclerview);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(_context));
    mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
            new RecyclerItemClickListener(_context, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                    logger.i("onitemClick");
                }

            })
    );
```

I have absolutely no idea how to determine which button within my cardview was clicked using the suggested practice. The problem is the whole cardview is returned instead of the item I click as shown in [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eN3Lg.png).

How can I determine which button was clicked? I'd like to avoid the viewholder suggestion in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick/) as I'm am doing lots of fragment transactions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement **Activity - Fragment - RecyclerView.Adapter** communication.
(fragment communication over interface pattern)

You should use one interface for **fragment-recyclerview.Adapter** communication and another for **activity-fragment** communication.

There is a good example(github) how to implement recyclerview but without fragments

**[antoniolg - RecyclerViewExtensions](https://github.com/antoniolg/RecyclerViewExtensions)**

---

There are my screenshots of code with blue background comments (todo) so you can follow  code flow, I use LongClick instead of Click and my ViewModel class is Friend/User, I have two disjunctional listviews so when somebody clicks on user it will migrate to friends list and vice versa.

[image: RecylclerAdapter]

---

[image: Fragment]

---

[image: Activity]

---

Please correct me if something is wrong with my explanation beacuse I am learning Android too.

Comment: I ended up doing this through the Adapter since it provides a getPosition method within the viewholder class. I am sure an interface solution would work fine but it is much more code to write.

Comment: Yes, it is, but after you learn the concept of interface communication between objects you will be most of the time use copy-paste of old code and change things what you need for particular project.

Comment: Completely agree, interface communication between objects (especially fragments) is extremely useful. Thanks for answering!

Comment: Try with Square Otto (event-bus) 
my example: I have two fragments with recyclerviews and when I press on first list item, the item will move to second fragment's recyclerview ( you should register and unregister bus everywhere where you are working with bus)

http://www.deviantpics.com/images/2015/01/15/otto.png